# Login functionality in cassandra database

Tags: authentication, cassandra, primary-key

I have a user table(column family) with userId as primary key, it also has other details like emailId, password, username etc.

My doubt is when user login using emailId, how to look for password in the table as my primary key is userId not emailId?

or is it better to create emailId is primary key?

or additional table for mapping userId with emailId?

Comment: Which version of Cassandra you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your Cassandra version supports Materialized View (3.x), here is what can be easily done

Say your original table schema is the following with userId being the primary key

```
create table userdetails_by_id 
(userId text primary key,
 emailId text,
 password text,
 username text);
```

Create a materialized view, where emailId would be the primary key and would contain all the other fields from main table. Here is its definition

```
create materialized view userdetails_by_emailid
as select 
userId,
emailId,
password,
username
from userdetails_by_id 
where userId is not null and emailId is not null
primary key (emailId, userId);
```

Now when the query is against userId, you can route it to the main table and query against emailId can be routed to the materialized view. This way Cassandra will keep the data in sync and extra application code isn't necessary to maintain two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Creating additional mapping table (emailId to userId) would require you to query two tables. This goes against design principles of Cassandra. Try to reduce the queries that you need to fire. In your case, a table with emailId as PRIMARY KEY would be necessary.